# Advice for listing multiple items like a catalog

Tags: asp-classic

I'm hoping someone might have a solution for a problem I have. I need a sort of catalog of used pianos complete with pricing, descriptions, etc. Previously someone else did it in a table, which was very ugly and hard to maintain. The problem is that our site is hosted on an asp server and I think the latest version of asp.net is 2.0. Our website is built in classic asp using includes to build the webpages server side. That's right, classic asp. I can't really think of a good solution to this problem. In the next 6 months we are going to move to an asp.net cms for our ecommerce, but for the next little while I have no other option but to use the asp site. Any help coming up with a maintainable solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Decoding your question ("...need a sort of..." => "...need to sort a..."  !=> "..need a type of..."), I think you have an HTML table that you want to sort.

Have you looked at http://datatables.net/ I have found it very good for this sort of thing

Good luck